# Assign classes for different tags in select2 multiselect

Tags: jquery, tags, jquery-select2, multi-select

Any ideas how I can pass a class to a jQuery select2 multiselect so I can style tags accordingly?

I have the following HTML:

```
<select data-placeholder="..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:100%;" tabindex="4">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="user1">John Smith</option>
      <option value="user2">Richard Branson</option>
      <option value="user3" class="guest">Tim Cook</option>
</select>
```

...and a simple js call:

```
$(".chosen-select").select2();
```

Note the "guest" class on the last option in the original HTML. I need to pass that class to the resulting tag generated in the select2 multiselect box so I can assign it a separate colour from the others.

Hopefully someone can help shed some light on it!